# How to minimize this sparse quadratic function?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-forms

There is a problem when I'm reading a paper.

Equation:

$min_p|p-p^*|^2+\alpha |R(p)|^2 + \beta |D(p)-\delta|^2$,

where $p, p^*, R(p), D(p), \delta$ are all $M\times N$ matrices, and $p^*, R(), D(), \delta$ are known.

The paper just mentioned "which (this equation) represents a sparse quadratic in $p$". According to this sentence, I cannot figure out how to solve this equation. Any hints would be appreciated.

Here is the [paper](http://faculty.cs.tamu.edu/schaefer/research/L0Smoothing.pdf). The equation is on Page 4, eq.6.

Comment: I think it should be possible to solve this problem with the direct method (Though I've never used it on finite dimensional problems). However, to get the equation of $p$ you might want to write down the Euler-Lagrange equation.

Comment: It seems to me that questions like this ought to be addressed to the authors. They clearly have a tendency for poor notation (if those are norms, specify what kind, and use $\|\cdot\|$, please!). And they committed the cardinal sin of using the term "$L_0$ norm", argh! But if we take them at their word that it is a sparse quadratic in $p$, then it is somehow equivalent to $\|A\mathop{\textbf{vec}}(p)-b\|_2^2$ for some constructed matrices $A$, $b$.